# Filling a Two-Dimensional Array

Tags: java, colors

I'm encountering a problem filling in the rows of my two dimensional array. I have to alternate between 3 colors, say red, white and blue..

```
public void makePattern()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++) {
            if (ROWS%3 == 0 && i < 15) {
                colors[i][j] = Color.RED;
                i = i + 3;
            }
            else if (ROWS%2 == 1 && i < 15) {
                i = 1;  
                colors[i][j] = Color.WHITE;
                i = i + 3;
            }
        }
    }
```

ROW = 15 
COLUMN = 20

I believe the code means that for every third row starting from 0 to 15 (0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15) fill it with red. then for the white for ever row starting from 1 until 15 and adding 3 (1, 4, 7, 10, 13) fill the row. There's still the matter of Blue, but I could do that after I understand this first. I end up filling the entire array Red. I need help to fix my code, but more importantly I need help understanding the logic of how this works, any advice or tip would be fine. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is just a hint, because this looks like a homework to me.

You should change the following line -

```
if (ROWS%3 == 0 && i < 15)
```

to -

```
if (i % 3 == 0)
```

This makes sure that you are selecting only the rows that are divisible by 3 (and also the first row with index 0 because you are checking for it first).

Your previous condition was checking for `ROW % 3`. If your ROW value is 15, this is true for every row. And the last `i < 15` bit is also always true.

Answer (score 0):

If you set `ROWS=15` and then you call `(if ROWS%15 ==0)` then you get everytime `true` as the result, because `ROWS` is set to 15 and you don't change that value during iterating through the loop. You'd probably want to do something like this:

```
public void makePattern()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++) {
            if ((i*j)%3 == 0 && i < 15) {
                colors[i][j] = Color.RED;
            }
            else if ((i*j)%2 == 1 && i < 15) {
                colors[i][j] = Color.WHITE;
            }
            else Colors[i][j] = Color.BLUE;
        }
    }
```

In addition - you really should not change the value of `i`, `j` or any other variable that you use for iteration, if it's not necessary needed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually what this code does is:

if your array consists of odd rows length then it's fill every 3rd row with red color and only for the first 15 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
if (ROWS%3 == 0 && i < 15)
```

to

```
if (i%3 == 0 && i < 15)
```

and also this line

```
else if (ROWS%2 == 1 && i < 15)
```

to

```
else if (i%2 == 1 && i < 15)
```

Since you are operating with ROWS which is always 15, u getting all as RED

Answer (score 0):

This should work (i admit, i didn't test yet) and is easily expandable to support more colors.

```
private Color[] colors= {Color.RED, Color.WHITE};

public void makePattern()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++) {
           colors[i][j] = colors[(ROWS * i + j) % colors.length];
        }
    }
}
```